# Push and Pop madness - Python not finding the target item

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape apartments.com with some help from Selenium and stuff it all into a CSV. My current method is to use '''driver.find_elements()''' to locate every element with the '''.placard''' CSS tag, but there are some annoying ads thrown into the mix also holding the '''.placard''' and '''.reinforcement''' tags.

I need to get these out of List, and my first idea is to Pop the offending elements. I can locate them with a presence_of_all_elements_located query, but my Pop strategy is plain not working.

Please see the code. Thank you

```
# Wait for the first page of listings to load
apartmentsTOBEDELETED = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reinforcement")))
print(len(apartmentsTOBEDELETED))
#output is 1 .reinforcement ad

apartments = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".placard")))
print(len(apartments))
#output is 26, including one "apartment" (the ad) with the ".placard" and ".reinforcement" CSS tag

#And now try to remove any apartment with the ".reinforcement" placard from the original list
i = 0
while i < len(apartments):
    if apartments[i].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reinforcement"):
        print("found the element TO BE DELETED")
        apartments.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1

**# Print the number of apartments in the filtered list**
print(len(apartments))
##output is 26. No pop.
```

Comment: The problem is that you're popping items off the list, thus changing its length, **while you're iterating over its length**.  The `while i < len(apartments)` loop condition gets out of sync with the actual list contents, and strange things happen.

Comment: The usual solution is not to remove items from the list at all, but instead create a **new** list that has only the items you want to keep.

Comment: I think this is the right answer! I'll try to implement and circle back tomorrow. Thanks John!

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the solution was as suggested. I created 3 lists, one with all the "ads" and one with all the "apartments", and a third for all the "filtered apartments"

For each apt in the apartments list, it was added into the list of filtered apartments, so long as none of the data overlapped with the data from the ad list

the code looked like this
`

```
        apartmentsTOBEDELETED = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reinforcement")))
        print(len(apartmentsTOBEDELETED))
        print("found an item to remove")# output is 1 .reinforcement ad - typically
        #capture all apartments
        apartments = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".placard")))

        # Create a new list of apartments that do not contain any reference to items in 'apartmentsTOBEDELETED'
        filtered_apartments = []
        for apartment in apartments:
            contains_deleted_item = False
            for deleted_item in apartmentsTOBEDELETED:
                if deleted_item.get_attribute('class') in apartment.get_attribute('class'):
                    contains_deleted_item = True
                    break
            if not contains_deleted_item:
                filtered_apartments.append(apartment)

        # Print the number of apartments in the filtered list
        print(len(filtered_apartments))
        print("now we have this many apartments left")
        apartments = filtered_apartments  # assign this to be the new list
```

`